# Editing tuples in a list of sml

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

I want to make a list which is of specification :(string*int) list and the tuples can be edited. For example, suppose

```
val gamma = [("a",20),("b",30),("c",40)] :(string*int) list
```

Now, how can I change the value `30` in the tuple `("b",30)` to , let's say, 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `map` over the list and build a new tuple:

```
let
  fun change key value (k, v) =
    if k = key
    then (k, value)
    else (k, v)

  val list = [("a",20),("b",30),("c",40)]
in
  List.map (change "b" 70) list
end
```

Comment: I want to create a map kind of data structure using list having specification :(string * int) list where first element is key and second element is value. Initially when I create this map, I just want to give key with no value. How can I pass null value in this case? For example, I need something like this when initializing:

    val gamma = [("a" , _ ),("b" , _ ),("c" , _ )] :(string*int) list.

Comment: I tried putting "_" and "NONE" but they didn't work.

Comment: @AnkitShubham that sounds like a totally separate question. I suggest you ask a new one using the StackOverflow system.